# GridView value should changed while data binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, enums

I want to change GridView column values.
I have created "Enum" to store my values in interger format in database. But when showing Gridview I want to display "Enum" text rather than values.
Currently I am displaying Enum int values in gridview Column.
Please help me to display string in gridview column

Here is my code to display gridview.

```
public void BindData()
{
    string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM ClientInfo";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "ClientInfo");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ClientInfo"].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

[Flow Column should display string instead of int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wOGB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. We have to create new function as follows:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell statusCell = e.Row.Cells[6];
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(statusCell.Text);
        Flows flowTypeName = (Flows)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Flows), value);
        statusCell.Text = flowTypeName.ToString();
    }
}
```

& we have to call that function in GridView as **OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"**

It is working properly now.